# wordpress search is not showing results from php templates assigned from backend

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, search

My wordpress search is showing results only from WYSIWYG, not from php templates assigned from admin panel.

I created a template page 'home.php' and assigned it for my home page using 'page attribute' in admin panel. In 'home.php' there is a word 'creativity'. So when i search for 'creativity' it is not showing. But if I put the same word in WYSIWYG, then it is showing in the search result.

What should i do to get results from php templates also.
Can anyone help me in this case.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to search any static content

Comment: can google search be able to show the word from this custom php template ?

Comment: Yes that can be possible